# Using Sed to edit my make.conf file

Tags: bash, sed

Okay, so I posted this a while ago & couldn't find much help. But I am making a auto-installation script for gentoo on a virtual box for a class I'm taking. My script can partition correctly, download the tarball correctly, (& extract), and I'm working on it CHROOTing correctly as well.

Anyways, I'm trying to use sed to change my make.conf like this:

```
sed -i 's/CFLAGS="-02 -pipe"/CFLAGS="-march=native -02 -pipe"/g' /mnt/gentoo/etc/portage/make.conf
```

And after this is run, I have a "cat /mnt/gentoo/etc/portage/make.conf" to look at the file to see if it worked. Which it doesn't. The version of sed is 4.2.1 if that helps at all. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is the relevant part of make.conf?

Comment: @choroba what do you mean?

Comment: Can you show the exact line from make.conf you want to replace?

Comment: @choroba the line is, : CFLAGS="-02 -pipe"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your command. What is in the file and what did you expect to be changed after?

Comment: @choroba which I want to change to, : CFLAGS="-march=native -02 -pipe"

Comment: As it is, I verified the command on a local file. It worked as expected. Probably, as a verification just copy the /mnt/gentoo/etc/portage/make.conf file to some local file and try. This will eliminate the possibility of file permission issue.

Comment: "Okay, so I posted this a while ago & couldn't find much help." I do have the impression of seeing the same question a while ago. Did you delete the older question and start a new one? If so, please refrain from this behavior. I believe you're abusing the system that way.

Comment: And I do remember someone suggesting that your `sed` might not have `-i`.

Comment: Post output of `[[ -w /mnt/gentoo/etc/portage/make.conf ]] && echo okay || echo "not okay"` and `sed -n '/CFLAGS="-02 -pipe"/p' /mnt/gentoo/etc/portage/make.conf` and `sed --version | head -n 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`-02` (zero two) would be a strange option. Presumably it's `-O2` (O two) instead.